# CodeRunner Version 3.0.1

Tags: coderunner

**In CodeRunner Version 3.0.1 not detecting separate C# class files in same folder **

Example following will compile

```
using System;


   public class Person {
   }


    class Student : Person {
     }
```

But if both each class has it's own file and in the same folder then the compiler reports:

The type or namespace name `Person' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Anyone any idea as how to sort this ?

Answer (score 0):

When compiling multiple C# files within CodeRunner, You must list your assembly files prior to the compilation by defining them **ALL** in your "*Run Settings*" under the "*Compile Flags*":

ex.

*/reference:System.Drawing ICar.cs M3.cs*

Hope this helps

note:
ICar.cs and M3.cs are my custom classes